# jQuery show multiple image thumbnail before upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made code for image preview before upload, but one problem.
How can i make to prewiev multiple images.
For example I have 3 images, so haw will jQuery know how many divs have to make for that images.

I think that I have to use for loop for that but not sure how.

This is my codes in HTML, CSS, and jQuery

```
<input id="file" type="file" name="file[]" required multiple/>
<div id="imagePreview"></div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#file").on("change", function()
        {
            var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
            if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) return; // no file selected, or no FileReader support

            if (/^image/.test( files[0].type)){ // only image file
            var reader = new FileReader(); // instance of the FileReader
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); // read the local file

            reader.onloadend = function(){ // set image data as background of div
            $("#imagePreview").css("background-image", "url("+this.result+")");
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
<style>
#imagePreview {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7s9krm2h/)

I just changed main script like this:

```
var inputLocalFont = document.getElementById("file");
inputLocalFont.addEventListener("change",previewImages,false);

function previewImages(){
    var fileList = this.files;

    var anyWindow = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

        for(var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){
          var objectUrl = anyWindow.createObjectURL(fileList[i]);
          $('#imagePreview').append('<img src="' + objectUrl + '" />');
          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileList[i]);
        }       
}
```